# Could add multiple data type of data into one list by one code??? C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I try to add multiple data type of data in one list.

```
public class DataList
{
    public List<int> DataOne=new List<int>();
    public int DataTwo;
    public double DataThree;
    public List<int> DataFour = new List<int>();

    public DataList(List<int> DataOne, int DataTwo, double DataThree, List<int> DataFour)
    {
      this.DataOne=DataOne;
      this.DataTwo=DataTwo; 
      this.DataThree=DataThree;
      this.DataFour=DataFour;
    }
}


public List<DataList> AddAllData = new List<final>();

AddAllData.Add(new DataList( ????? )); //<-Could add multiple data by one code?
```

thank you Guy solve this.

---

But
for more: if

```
public class One
{
    public List<int> OneLise=new List<int>();
    public List<double> TwoLise=new List<int>();

    public One(List<int> OneLise, int TwoLise)
    {
      this.OneLise=OneLise;
      this.TwoLise=TwoLise; 

    }
}



public class DataList
{
    public List<One> DataOne=new List<One>();
    public int DataTwo;

    public DataList(List<One> DataOne, int DataTwo)
    {
      this.DataOne=DataOne;
      this.DataTwo=DataTwo; 

    }
}

AddAllData.Add(new DataList( ????? )); //<-Could add multiple data by one code?
```

e.g:something like that

```
AddAllData.Add(new DataList(DataOne.Add(5,2.3), 1, 5.3, DataFour.Add(4,2.65)));
```

---

I know one of method:

```
 public List<one> one = new List<one>();
 one.Add(5,2.3);
 public List<one> four = new List<one>();
 four.Add(4,2.65);
 AddAllData.Add(new DataList(one, 1, 5.3, four));
```

but it need more code to add data into list.

if AddAllData is more that 1000 element. it is waste time to add data

How to add multiple data type of data into one list by one code?

Comment: Does https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc(v=vs.110).aspx#Examples help?

Comment: you can try to use a dynamic object

Comment: Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628222/creating-a-list-of-lists-in-c-sharp

Comment: Thank you. but AddRange is not helpful. when add first element in list "AddAllData", i need to add DataOne list and DataOne element to AddAllData at the same time

Comment: yes use ArrayList

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the parameters to all the `DataList` manually or read them from file. But you can initialize `AddAllData` with `DataList` objects like this

```
// 3 DataLists example
List<DataList> AddAllData = new List<DataList>
{
    new DataList(new List<int> {5}, 1, 5.3, new List<int> {4}),
    new DataList(new List<int> {7}, 6, 4.3, new List<int> {9}),
    new DataList(new List<int> {3, 5}, 4, 5.3, new List<int> {4, 6, 7})
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I try to follow this structure.