# I can't deserialize json file

Tags: c#, json

1) json:

```
[[{"Id":6,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3633976.6,"EstimatedPower":3529887.3134946576,"Consumption":210687.426175765,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":-2.864335629055581,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":7,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3087296.2,"EstimatedPower":2937010.8697607126,"Consumption":181808.811123168,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-4.8678623787146709,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":8,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3789773.0,"EstimatedPower":4062749.0288516344,"Consumption":248780.849474034,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":7.2029651604894163,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":9,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":4147530.6,"EstimatedPower":4013436.2063861224,"Consumption":249512.711123168,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-3.2331140272690906,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":10,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3526440.2,"EstimatedPower":3646342.5469404678,"Consumption":234718.429474034,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":3.4000958513479951,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":11,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3246991.6,"EstimatedPower":3168656.9042940191,"Consumption":211549.901123168,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":-2.4125315170504646,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":12,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2396363.0,"EstimatedPower":2416626.8007339239,"Consumption":159345.971123168,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":0.84560647672844436,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":114,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1021862.2,"EstimatedPower":1076057.4491338292,"Consumption":89701.7655810564,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":5.3035770511747238,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":115,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1144715.8,"EstimatedPower":1108039.9497605087,"Consumption":89681.9904647411,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-3.2039262705635174,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":116,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1074957.4,"EstimatedPower":1182082.0678394337,"Consumption":96818.4488368462,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":9.9654802915384089,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":117,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1243359.8,"EstimatedPower":1239392.9877877974,"Consumption":100238.590464741,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-0.31903976726629368,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":118,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1094505.4,"EstimatedPower":1239985.6629106368,"Consumption":97751.6488368462,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":13.291872558201812,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":119,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":766071.2,"EstimatedPower":1293214.0524931694,"Consumption":99903.100464741,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":68.811208735319823,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":120,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2048921.6,"EstimatedPower":1243607.6504395444,"Consumption":97391.090464741,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":-39.304283265911963,"Excluded":[3],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":66,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2375411.4,"EstimatedPower":2598429.5959766749,"Consumption":241303.937741935,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":9.38861352507927,"Excluded":[4],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":67,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2816367.0,"EstimatedPower":2761899.1710119839,"Consumption":270116.242857143,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-1.9339748331100304,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":68,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2885174.8,"EstimatedPower":2951451.2435807148,"Consumption":283105.451152074,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":2.2971378919819596,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":69,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3089902.2,"EstimatedPower":2900149.1745301066,"Consumption":283664.742857143,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-6.1410689784904378,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":70,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3227620.0,"EstimatedPower":2780273.3585052835,"Consumption":284044.431152074,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":-13.859953820298443,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":71,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2471207.0,"EstimatedPower":2790993.2908156421,"Consumption":295357.502857143,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":12.940489842236701,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":72,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2751209.6,"EstimatedPower":2848408.6166038075,"Consumption":293990.002857143,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":3.5329557080568286,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}]]
```

2) code:

```
string jsonList;

List<EnergyPlanningResult> allData;
try
{
    allData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<EnergyPlanningResult>>(jsonList);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e);
    throw;
}
```

The error message is:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'MonitoringOfEnergyConsumption.Controllers.EnergyPlanningResult' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '[0]', line 1, position 2.
```

I've checked the json file and it's valid.

I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: The error message spells it out very clearly. The JSON represents an array. The value you assign to an `EnergyPlanningResult` needs to be an object.

Comment: You want array(`List`) of objects(`EnergyPlanningResult`) but your JSON encodes array of arrays of objects. You have to change one or another to match.

Comment: How to do first one?

Comment: Is the language you're using to read your json data java? Could you add a tag to identify it, please?

Comment: It's not Java. It's C#.

Answer (score 0):

Post your Json in this website: http://pojo.sodhanalibrary.com and get your matching java pojo.

Like above, many websites are available online to convert JSON to Java Pojo directly, use one of it, if you are unsure about your model.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this is simple, your json:

```
[[{"Id":6,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3633976.6,"EstimatedPower":3529887.3134946576,"Consumption":210687.426175765,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":-2.864335629055581,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":7,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3087296.2,"EstimatedPower":2937010.8697607126,"Consumption":181808.811123168,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-4.8678623787146709,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":8,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3789773.0,"EstimatedPower":4062749.0288516344,"Consumption":248780.849474034,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":7.2029651604894163,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":9,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":4147530.6,"EstimatedPower":4013436.2063861224,"Consumption":249512.711123168,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-3.2331140272690906,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":10,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3526440.2,"EstimatedPower":3646342.5469404678,"Consumption":234718.429474034,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":3.4000958513479951,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":11,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3246991.6,"EstimatedPower":3168656.9042940191,"Consumption":211549.901123168,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":-2.4125315170504646,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":12,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2396363.0,"EstimatedPower":2416626.8007339239,"Consumption":159345.971123168,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":0.84560647672844436,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":114,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1021862.2,"EstimatedPower":1076057.4491338292,"Consumption":89701.7655810564,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":5.3035770511747238,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":115,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1144715.8,"EstimatedPower":1108039.9497605087,"Consumption":89681.9904647411,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-3.2039262705635174,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":116,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1074957.4,"EstimatedPower":1182082.0678394337,"Consumption":96818.4488368462,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":9.9654802915384089,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":117,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1243359.8,"EstimatedPower":1239392.9877877974,"Consumption":100238.590464741,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-0.31903976726629368,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":118,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1094505.4,"EstimatedPower":1239985.6629106368,"Consumption":97751.6488368462,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":13.291872558201812,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":119,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":766071.2,"EstimatedPower":1293214.0524931694,"Consumption":99903.100464741,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":68.811208735319823,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":120,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2048921.6,"EstimatedPower":1243607.6504395444,"Consumption":97391.090464741,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":-39.304283265911963,"Excluded":[3],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":66,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2375411.4,"EstimatedPower":2598429.5959766749,"Consumption":241303.937741935,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":9.38861352507927,"Excluded":[4],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":67,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2816367.0,"EstimatedPower":2761899.1710119839,"Consumption":270116.242857143,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-1.9339748331100304,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":68,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2885174.8,"EstimatedPower":2951451.2435807148,"Consumption":283105.451152074,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":2.2971378919819596,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":69,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3089902.2,"EstimatedPower":2900149.1745301066,"Consumption":283664.742857143,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-6.1410689784904378,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":70,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3227620.0,"EstimatedPower":2780273.3585052835,"Consumption":284044.431152074,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":-13.859953820298443,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":71,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2471207.0,"EstimatedPower":2790993.2908156421,"Consumption":295357.502857143,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":12.940489842236701,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":72,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2751209.6,"EstimatedPower":2848408.6166038075,"Consumption":293990.002857143,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":3.5329557080568286,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}]]
```

is not a valid json. this is because of the **double square bracets**.

remove one square bracet, you're json will loke like:

```
[{"Id":6,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3633976.6,"EstimatedPower":3529887.3134946576,"Consumption":210687.426175765,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":-2.864335629055581,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":7,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3087296.2,"EstimatedPower":2937010.8697607126,"Consumption":181808.811123168,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-4.8678623787146709,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":8,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3789773.0,"EstimatedPower":4062749.0288516344,"Consumption":248780.849474034,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":7.2029651604894163,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":9,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":4147530.6,"EstimatedPower":4013436.2063861224,"Consumption":249512.711123168,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-3.2331140272690906,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":10,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3526440.2,"EstimatedPower":3646342.5469404678,"Consumption":234718.429474034,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":3.4000958513479951,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":11,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3246991.6,"EstimatedPower":3168656.9042940191,"Consumption":211549.901123168,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":-2.4125315170504646,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":12,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2396363.0,"EstimatedPower":2416626.8007339239,"Consumption":159345.971123168,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":0.84560647672844436,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":114,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1021862.2,"EstimatedPower":1076057.4491338292,"Consumption":89701.7655810564,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":5.3035770511747238,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":115,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1144715.8,"EstimatedPower":1108039.9497605087,"Consumption":89681.9904647411,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-3.2039262705635174,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":116,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1074957.4,"EstimatedPower":1182082.0678394337,"Consumption":96818.4488368462,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":9.9654802915384089,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":117,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1243359.8,"EstimatedPower":1239392.9877877974,"Consumption":100238.590464741,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-0.31903976726629368,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":118,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":1094505.4,"EstimatedPower":1239985.6629106368,"Consumption":97751.6488368462,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":13.291872558201812,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":119,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":766071.2,"EstimatedPower":1293214.0524931694,"Consumption":99903.100464741,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":68.811208735319823,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":120,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2048921.6,"EstimatedPower":1243607.6504395444,"Consumption":97391.090464741,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":-39.304283265911963,"Excluded":[3],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}],[{"Id":66,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-02-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2375411.4,"EstimatedPower":2598429.5959766749,"Consumption":241303.937741935,"Temperature":-16.0,"Deviation":9.38861352507927,"Excluded":[4],"IsOutlier":true,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":67,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-03-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2816367.0,"EstimatedPower":2761899.1710119839,"Consumption":270116.242857143,"Temperature":-4.5,"Deviation":-1.9339748331100304,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":68,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-04-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2885174.8,"EstimatedPower":2951451.2435807148,"Consumption":283105.451152074,"Temperature":-9.9,"Deviation":2.2971378919819596,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":69,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-05-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3089902.2,"EstimatedPower":2900149.1745301066,"Consumption":283664.742857143,"Temperature":-4.7,"Deviation":-6.1410689784904378,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":70,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-06-01T00:00:00Z","Power":3227620.0,"EstimatedPower":2780273.3585052835,"Consumption":284044.431152074,"Temperature":6.6,"Deviation":-13.859953820298443,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":71,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-07-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2471207.0,"EstimatedPower":2790993.2908156421,"Consumption":295357.502857143,"Temperature":16.0,"Deviation":12.940489842236701,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false},{"Id":72,"CalculationMethod":"Потребление факт, кВт⋅ч","ProcessId":1,"Date":"2017-08-01T00:00:00Z","Power":2751209.6,"EstimatedPower":2848408.6166038075,"Consumption":293990.002857143,"Temperature":9.5,"Deviation":3.5329557080568286,"Excluded":[],"IsOutlier":false,"IsSelected":true,"IsNew":false,"IsModified":false,"IsDeleted":false}]
```

In json, `[{}]` means an array, so you can deserialize it into a list for example.

{}  means a single object and you can deserialize it into a class representation for example.

**One Note**

if you want to work with the existing json format, you will have to work with a list of lists as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12628222/creating-a-list-of-lists-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I've created json file as you'd suggested, but got the error message: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 2352".

Comment: It says json file is not valid: "Error: Parse error on line 113:
...IsDeleted": false}], [{ "Id": 114, "C
----------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', got ','".